# Layout_margin is not working

Tags: android

I want to use margin in my layout.But it's not working.This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/blocks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mes7"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:clickable="false">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:text="Test Message"
    android:textSize="12dp"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:text="19:40"
    android:textSize="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Why layout_margin is not working ?

Ps:I am using it with a listview.

Comment: Make your top LinearLayout have `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: I tried it but not worked.

Comment: You actually don't need the top LinearLayout. Remove that and add the layout width to the remaining LinearLayout.

Answer (score 3):

because you set `width` and `height` to `wrap_content` , change them specially parent `LinearLayout` to `match_parent`

Comment: do it for another LinearLayout also

Comment: so maybe your ListView tag have layout_width="wrap_content",is it true ?!!

Comment: I test your xml every thing was good, but try to use relativeLayout instead. your time was not align true in linearlayout